# No reconoce el IF, ELSE, END; pero si ejecuta lo que esta dentro de la sentencia en Oracle

Tags: oracle

Si lo ejecuto en OracleSQlDeveloper(Ver 22), corre todo bien, si ejecuto el .bat por cmd, llama al .sql, se queda colgado y tengo que terminar la ejecución.
Como prueba, comento todo menos el DECLARE y se queda colgado el proceso tambien.
Tengo el Oracle 11g. Me pueden decir como o con que ejecutan ustedes el .sql fuera del Developer para que funcione?
Gracias y saludos

```
SET serveroutput ON
    DECLARE
        ResulCons NUMBER;
        starFlag VARCHAR2(50);
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(1) INTO ResulCons FROM SKURESP230711 WHERE ITEM = 'AGUACATE311' AND LOC = 'PAS01';
        IF ResulCons = 0 THEN 
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ResulCons: ' || ResulCons);
            starFlag := 'UPDATESKU inserto';
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('starFlag: ' || starFlag);
            INSERT INTO SKURESP230711 (ITEM, LOC, CREATIONDATE) VALUES ('AGUACATE311','PAS01',To_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YY'));
        ELSE 
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ResulCons: ' || ResulCons);
             starFlag := 'UPDATESKU actualizo';
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('starFlag: ' || starFlag);
            UPDATE SKURESP230711 SET CREATIONDATE = to_char(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YY') WHERE ITEM = 'AGUACATE3211' AND LOC = 'PAS01';
         END IF;
        COMMIT;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATESKU completado.');
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATESKU  con error: ' || SQLERRM);
    END;

    DISCONNECT;
    EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;

Este es el output:
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Lun Ago 14 15:22:07 2023
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

 27   28  
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: Puedes agregar una descripción mas completa de lo que quieres lograr, es un procedimiento anónimo por lo que veo y tiene algunos errores, recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta las veces que sean necesarias.

Comment: Asignar es con `:=` y comparar es con `=`...

Comment: Antonio, estoy usando Oracle11g y 12c, de un .bat ejecuto .sql con el codigo publicado. Trabaja los SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, no reconoce el IF, ELSE, END, CASE, SET, DECLARE, BEGIN, END; no se si tenga que declarar algo mas para que trabaje estos comandos. Lo ejecuto en OracleSQLDeveloper(Ver 22 y 19), mismo resultado. Ocupo el resultado del SELECT para hacer el UPDATE o el INSERT, y una variable para asignar un texto de lo ejecutado (UPDATE o INSERT), y que al regresar al .bat, evaluar si contina con un siguiente paso o cierra el batch, dejando registro en un .log

Comment: padaleiana, ya lo ejecute con := al asignar, pero no lo toma

Comment: Antonio y padaleiana, quiero desplegar el contenido de la variable y no reconoce el DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT.LINE, ni por el .sql ni por el OracleSQLDeveloper. Nota: No reconoce el CASE, estoy confundido el porque no esta interpretando los comandos, no se si es el compilador de Oracle o que pasa, lo he probado linea por linea, obteniendo "instrucción no reconocida", o se queda congelada la ejecución y tengo que abortar la ejecución, gracias y saludos,

Comment: Javier, cuando menciones a alguien, utiliza el @ (menciona solo a un usuario por comentario). Tuve que visitar la pregunta de nuevo para leer lo que escribiste. Por otra parte: es `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`...

Comment: @AntonioGalicia Si lo ejecuto en OracleSQLDeveloper y funciona quitqndo la parte del else, al correrlo con un .bat en cmd, se queda congelado. Me comentaste que lo procesaste y te funciono bien. Como o con que lo corres fuera del developer para que corra con exito? Gracias y saludos

Comment: @padaleiana Actualize la pregunta y puse imagen. Como o con que lo corres fuera del developer para que corra con exito? Gracias y saludos,

Comment: Por favor, los mensajes de error y el código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Por cierto... ¿conocés la barra (_slash_, `/`)? Si no, _buscá qué hace_.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle PL/SQL no utiliza la sintaxis IF, ELSE y END

```
    SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
    ResulCons NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO ResulCons FROM SKURESP230711 WHERE ITEM = 'Galletas555' AND LOC = 'ALM01';
    
    IF ResulCons = 0 THEN 
       UPDATE SKURESP230711 SET CREATIONDATE = to_char(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YY') WHERE ITEM = 'Galletas555' AND LOC = 'ALM01';
    ELSE 
      INSERT INTO SKURESP230711 (ITEM, LOC, CREATIONDATE) VALUES ('Galletas555','ALM01',To_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YY'));
    END IF;
    
    COMMIT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Proceso completado.');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

se utiliza BEGIN para iniciar un bloque de código y END para finalizarlo. Además, para comparar valores, se utiliza el operador = en lugar de ==.

Recuerda que en PL/SQL, las sentencias DML (como UPDATE e INSERT) deben ser encapsuladas en un bloque BEGIN-END

Comment: _Oracle PL/SQL no utiliza la sintaxis IF, ELSE y END_: claro, es `IF...THEN - ELSE - END IF`.

Comment: Katia, en el .bat mando llamar: sqlplus: sqlplus SYSTEM/SYSTEM @C:\ScriptTst\GGUPDATESKU.sql -r1 l> outputUPD.txt. Le puse tu codigo al .sql. lo ejecuto: ***** UPDATE comienza 15:44:06.43 *****  ^C¿Desea terminar el trabajo por lotes (S/N)? s
Se queda congelado..lo aborto, da esto en el output.txt: Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
 20  ..

Comment: quita el -r1 y prueba

Comment: Katia, se queda congelado, el output da: SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Vie Ago 11 16:02:09 2023

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: padaleiana, ya lo habia probado: IF ResulCons == 0 THEN 
 UPDATE SKURESP230711 SET CREATIONDATE= to_char(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YY') WHERE ITEM = 'Galletas555' AND LOC = 'ALM01';
ELSE 
   INSERT INTO SKURESP230711 (ITEM, LOC, CREATIONDATE) VALUES('Galletas555','ALM01',To_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YY'));
END IF;. Da esto en el output.txt: SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "IF ResulCo..." - rest of line ignored. 3 rows updated.
SP2-0042: unknown command "ELSE" - rest of line ignored. 1 row created.
SP2-0042: unknown command "END IF" - rest of line ignored

Comment: actualicé mi respuesta fijate ahi.

Comment: @JavierNunez No me llegan notificaciones si no usas el "@". De nuevo: _comparar es con `=`, no con `==`..._ Además, tus intentos deben ir como edición a la pregunta, no a través de comentarios. Como verás, el código es ilegible aquí.

Comment: @KatiaSisHost lo ejecuto en OracleSQLDeveloper y funciona todo bien, al correrlo con un .bat en cmd, se queda congelado, Como o con que lo corres fuera del developer para que corra con exito? Actualize la pregunta, gracias y saludos